# Angular two way binding not working same way as plunker

Tags: angularjs, express, babeljs, nunjucks

Angular view(template) is not updating but scopes are up to date when looking on batarang this when coded to be served on express.

After creating the same code on Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/gHTFVkyDBIoJTvNMOgeB?p=preview where works really well when changing the select option:

`<p>Hello {{selectedPlan.name}}!</p>`  line in template where not working on express

**Differences**:

Plunker on root path

Express path: http://localhost:3000/advertisement/add-new

Template path: http://localhost:3000/templates/plan-selector.nunjucks

I added the minimal setup that I have with babelify on github so if someone can test https://github.com/carlitux/angular-test and also I added two screenshoots.

https://github.com/carlitux/angular-test/blob/master/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-02%20at%2011.17.14%20AM.png this has initial values where don't render the controller scope value.

https://github.com/carlitux/angular-test/blob/master/Screen%20Shot%202016-05-02%20at%2011.17.32%20AM.png this after the directive plan-selector changed also didn't render on template.

But on both images you can see the scope is there updated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question.

Comment: [Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/gHTFVkyDBIoJTvNMOgeB?p=preview) in your question is working fine. You gotta upload the code which is not working.

Comment: sorry I updated the link, I am wondering why on plunker is working as should updating... <p>Hello {{selectedPlan.name}}!</p>. But when I put same code on express doesn't update it on view(template) but scopes are updated (I can see in batarang)

Comment: Just edited, I hope this is more clear

Comment: Have a look at your URL, `http://localhost:3000//advertisement/add-new`. why two `/` before `advertisement`?

Comment: just a typo here... on browser loads well but updates on template not working but scopes are up to date... I tried to use $scope.$apply but raises $digest is in progress.

Answer (score 1):

Guys first of all this was my mistake... a newbie error but maybe someone will have the same error and could help.

As I am using **nunjucks** template engine I need to config the interpolate for angular... this as **nunjucks** uses {{ and }} to render variables the rendered template by **nunjucks** is empty or default value and angular don't have the {{ }} in the template to get rendered.

Here is the needed changes to get it working on express, nunjucks, angular.

https://github.com/carlitux/angular-test/commit/7aac83d16b10216885c20068ffe2dd3f3f9f2f91